# How to make Mongoose not save a field if not listed on the schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, schema

For example if I send a post request saving new user and add an additional field `"Name": "oscar"` this field is saving to mongodb event if is not listed on the schema. I need to prevent this from saving if is not listed on the schema.

```
const User = new Schema(
  {
    userName: {
      type: String,
      required: schemaErrorRequired('login'),
      unique: schemaErrorUnique('login'),
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: schemaErrorRequired('email'),
      unique: schemaErrorUnique('email'),
    },
    pass: {
      type: String,
      required: 'Save error',
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is not happening with mongoose 5.8

Answer (score 0):

add options to schema { strict : false}